# child view ignore parent view padding so it fits full width

Tags: javascript, reactjs, css, react-native, flexbox

parent view:

```
<ScrollView style={{backgroundColor:'#460547', padding: 70}}>
```

child view:

```
<View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
```

How can i make the child view ignore the parent view padding, so it fits the entire width?.
[image]

Comment: can you give an screenshot?

Comment: i've added one @Arup Rakshit

Comment: Just take padding off parent and put it on the children that need it